# divide 100 in to 5 spots with each spot getting twice as much as the one before

Tags: number-theory

OK, so say I have $100 and I want to break it up between 5 people, but I want to make is so every person gets twice as much as that last person...

What % would each person get?

How would I get this?  As you can see from the pictures, I am guessing at best but I am sure there has to be a better way, no matter how long the number might be.

This is my first try. . 
[image: This is my first idea]

Here is my long about way. . 
[image: Me trying, and I know there has to be a better way]

Is there a formula of some kind I can use?

Comment: Have you thought about multiplying your number by $31$?  (Hint: $1 + 2 + 4 + 8 + 16 = 31$.)

Answer (score 2):

Let the first person get $x$. Then the other four get $2x,4x,8x$, and $16x$, so we must choose $x$ to satisfy $x+2x+4x+8x+16x=100$, or $31x=100$. Thus, $x=\frac{100}{31}\approx 3.225806451613$. Once you have this, getting the other four values is straightforward. The same method can be applied to any number of people.

Comment: When I do what Brian suggest I end up with this.  
  
3.225806451613 + 

6.451612903226 + 

12.903225806452 + 

25.806451612904 + 

51.612903225808 = 

100.000000000003   

I know at this point, that is super close and its just me wanting to know if I can get to a solid number (100) but is that as close as I can get?

Comment: @Chaos67731: The decimal equivalent of $\frac{100}{31}$ does not terminate, so no matter how many decimal places you keep, the result won’t be exact. The more decimal places you keep, the closer to $100$ the total will be. You can do a little better if instead of multiplying $3.22580645613$ by $2,4,8$, and $16$, you compute $\frac{200}{31}$, $\frac{400}{31}$, $\frac{800}{31}$, and $\frac{1600}{31}$ to the same number of decimal places and add; this reduces the roundoff error slightly.

Comment: Thank you!  The formula you gave is very helpful!

Comment: @Chaos67731: You’re welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Just think about the problem. Let $x$ be the amount in dollars that the first person gets (that is the person who receives money first). Then the next person gets their share, they get $2x$. Then next person would get twice that, that is to say $8x$, etc. Now their total amount of money should be $100$. So we have $$x+2x+4x+8x+16x=31=100$$ Then the first person receives $100/31$ dollars. The rest of the calculations for the other peoples share are easy to calculate. Just don't forget to change their amounts into percentages (here this is easy as what they receive is their percentage as the amount of money is $100).